# Write a List to google Sheets

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, nested-lists

I have a list of strings. I wish to import this into a google spreadsheet so that each list is a new row.

List is as below:

```
['[, Hakim BEN EL HADJ, 64, 4, 12]', '[, Wilfried BIEN, 49, 4, 10]', '[, Ruddy BUQUET, 43, 3, 10]', '[, Tony CHAPRON, 53, 1, 10]', '[, Amaury DELERUE, 37, 0, 8]', '[, Saïd ENNJIMI, 35, 1, 8]', '[, Fredy FAUTREL, 32, 2, 11]', '[, Antony GAUTIER, 40, 9, 11]', '[, Johan HAMEL, 45, 7, 10]', '[, Lionel JAFFREDO, 48, 2, 11]', '[, Stéphane JOCHEM, 41, 4, 10]', '[, Stéphane LANNOY, 28, 0, 7]', '[, Mikael LESAGE, 47, 6, 11]', '[, François LETEXIER, 3, 0, 1]', '[, Jérôme MIGUELGORRY, 37, 1, 11]', '[, Benoît MILLOT, 46, 0, 12]', '[, Sébastien MOREIRA, 47, 5, 12]', '[, Nicolas RAINVILLE, 45, 7, 12]', '[, Frank SCHNEIDER, 38, 6, 12]', '[, Clément TURPIN, 33, 3, 10]', '[, Bartolomeu VARELA, 42, 3, 11]']
```

I would like this to output as:

```
Hakim BEN EL HADJ, 64, 4, 12
Wilfried BIEN,     49 ,4, 12
Ruddy BUQUET,      43, 3, 10.......
```

i.e. a table. How would I go about doing this. The problem seems to be that you need a cell reference for each individual bit of data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a .csv file and import that into Google sheets.

```
import csv

yourList = [['Hakim BEN EL HADJ', '64', '4', '12'], ['Wilfried BIEN', '49', '4', '10']]

with open('File.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for data in yourList:
        writer.writerow(data)
```

This produces [csvExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwHYX.png)

Which in turn gives [Google sheets example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sFe9.png) when imported to Google sheets

Comment: Thank you Carl. I was rather hoping that there would be a way to do this without having to write to a CSV file?

Comment: Hmm not sure about that one unfortunately, never made anything specifically for Sheets.